# How to select or activate main camera only in Android 10 custom ROM

Tags: camera, initialization, android-10.0, rom, unify

What Android 10 source code must be modified to ensure only the main or rear camera is called by any application accessing the system's cameras?

I have built a custom Android 10 ROM for my phablet which has only one camera.  I would like to unify the camera on my ROM so that applications which request the front camera (Zoom, Teams, Skype) cannot crash the system and only open the main/rear camera (only camera).

//Successful launch of main camera (only camera)
mCameraId=0, prev:fd=81, vir=0xe1939000, num=1468, width=960, height=720, time=1305745194872

//Want to prevent the failure of camera initialization
12-11 17:09:58.405 14315 14385 W CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 1: Status(-8, EX_SERVICE_SPECIFIC): '10: connectHelper:1512: Failed to initialize camera "1": Function not implemented (-38)'

camera_init: hal_err failed to init camera -1

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with custom ROMs.